# Can you identify this flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

Can you identify this flower??

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like calendula, otherwise known as pot marigold, to me.

Comment: I'm interested in the other plants alongside it though, looks like it's been planted as a companion for vegetables (are they carrot, and parsley or parsnip or something?).

Comment: you won't believee, but I know nothing about other plants. I can take more photos. Are you sure it is marigold? I believe you, but leaves don't seem to entirely match.

Comment: Aleksandr - "Pot Marigold" (genus: Calendula) is different from "Marigold" ("Genus: Tagetes, unless they've changed it recently). The plants near it look like carrot (wild relative or domesticated) to me, but they could easily be a parsley or many other plants.